# Html selection all it works. but it throws error when select with `space`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a selection, and on highlight i adding a space. when user select the same span, i console the message.

all working fine. but when i select a existing node element (strong) with space, i am getting an error as `The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.`

how to solve this?

here is my code :

```
var currentTarget = null;
function selHTML() {
    var nNd = document.createElement("span");
    var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();  
    currentTarget = $(w.startContainer).parent();

    //console.log(selection.anchorNode.baseURI);//nextElementSibling/anchorNode

    if(!$(w.startContainer).parent().prop('class')) {

        if($.trim(text).length < 5 ) {
            console.log("Your selection is too short..!");
            return;
        }

        try {
            w.surroundContents(nNd);
            currentTarget.find('span.highlight').contents().unwrap();
            $(nNd).addClass('highlight');
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.")
        }

    } else {
        console.log("already selected");
    }



}


$("#addText").on('click',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selHTML());
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $(selHTML());
});

$("#clearSpan").click(function(){
    console.log($(currentTarget))
});

$("div.content").mouseup(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (!range.collapsed) {
        var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = bounds.left + ((bounds.right - bounds.left - $(".savetooltipAll").outerWidth()) / 2);
        var y = bounds.top - $(".savetooltipAll").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".savetooltipAll").css("top", (y+(bounds.top*3)) + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").css("left",x + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").show();

    } else {
        $(".savetooltipAll").hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8aoybL8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight selected text on a page when spanning multiple non text nodes:
[Highlight selected text on a page when spanning multiple non text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677683/highlight-selected-text-on-a-page-when-spanning-multiple-non-text-nodes)

Comment: Yes it will work, But i would like to add a `span` or `classname` and i require the parent of selected text... all not possible there..

Comment: This is because getSelection returns a documentFragment that has 'no parent'

Comment: Haha like this, a good idea. [adding-h1-around-a-selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221555/adding-h1-around-a-selection)

Comment: @Marlin, they using some plugin-in. is there a way to solve without a pulg-in?

Comment: am also interesred in this issue. @3gwebtrain